# laravel как передать массив post в контроллер?

Tags: php, laravel

Вот что пытаюсь сделать в роутерах:

```
Route::post('/reg','Auth\RegisterController@create');
```

И метод контроллера:

```
protected function create(array $data) //Регистрация пользователя
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'soc_auth' => $data['soc_auth'],
        'session' => $data['session'],
        'stats' => $data['stats'],
        'reg_date' => time(),
        'info' => $data['info'],
        'status' => $data['status'],
        'messages' => $data['messages']
    ]);
}
```

Вопрос, как сделать чтобы Post данные попали в массив $data?

Comment: Используйте public function create(Request $request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function create(Request $request)
{
   $data = $request->get('data');

   ***
}
```